# Need some help with text color suggestion

Tags: color, color-scheme

I'm a developer and I created a page with some photos with names on them. I'm not sure what would be the ideal color to visibly display them. I tried Blue and White. Attaching the screenshots of the same.

[image]

[image]

Can someone please suggest to me what could be the best color to be used for text to display sharp? Any other suggestions like adding a background or adding opacity are also welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Use white but with black outline or shadow (in CSS something like `text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000`)

Answer (score 3):

- Font-weight: bold or extra-bold
- Color: any color at maximum saturation or white
- Black outline to the text as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4919231/5765312).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the best solution. given the placement of the text, there will never be an ideal colour. Any colour picked has a likelihood of being lost in the details on the drivers jumpsuit.

you should probably look for other solutions

- Change the placement of the text.
- if the requirements align, the name can appear only on hover
- Have a background behind the text to make sure its clear. it could be semi transparent